# Request.Form not working while using masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, request.form

I am working on ecommerce website. At final I need to integrate payment gateway for which I am using payuBiz. While parsing Trasaction infromation to payu I have notice Request.Form values are empty & that's what creating problem for me. Also The code works fine if I don't use master page. It's hust not working with master page.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MERCHANT_KEY"))
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(txnid1) 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form(amount.ClientID)) 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form(firstName.ClientID)) 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form(email.ClientID)) 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form(phone.ClientID)) 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form(productInfo.ClientID)) 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form(surl.ClientID)) 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form(furl.ClientID))) {
    //error

    frmError.Visible = true;
    return;
} else {
    string myAmount = amount.Text;
    frmError.Visible = false;
    hashVarsSeq = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("hashSequence").Split('|');
    // spliting hash sequence from config
    hash_string = "";
    foreach (string hash_var in hashVarsSeq) {
        if (hash_var == "key") {
            hash_string = hash_string + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MERCHANT_KEY");
            hash_string = hash_string + Convert.ToString('|');
        } else if (hash_var == "txnid") {
            hash_string = hash_string + txnid1;
            hash_string = hash_string + Convert.ToString('|');
        } else if (hash_var == "amount") {
            hash_string = hash_string + Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form(hash_var)).ToString("g29");
            hash_string = hash_string + Convert.ToString('|');

        } else {
            hash_string = hash_string + Convert.ToString((Request.Form(hash_var) != null ? Request.Form(hash_var) : ""));
            // isset if else
            hash_string = hash_string + Convert.ToString('|');
        }
    }

    hash_string += ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SALT");
    // appending SALT
    hash1 = Generatehash512(hash_string).ToLower();
    //generating hash
    // setting URL
    action1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PAYU_BASE_URL") + "/_payment";


}
```

Comment: In what event are you coding that?

Comment: @kblok it's on Button click event

Comment: Just for debugging, could you break in that event and, Run this in the Inmmediate Window `Request.Form.ToString()` and share the results?

Comment: Request.Form[this.TextBox.UniqueID] worked for me

Answer (score 0):

When using a Master Page, the `name` and `id` of a control are renamed to something like this.

```
<input type="test "name="ctl00$mainContentPane$TextBox1" id="ctl00_mainContentPane_TextBox1">
```

And while you indeed use `ClientID` for Client side purposes (hence the name) like javascript to get the correct ID, but in a form post the `name` is used to get the value. So use `UniqueID`

```
string value = Request.Form[TextBox1.UniqueID];
```

But why not use the values as you would normally, like `string value = TextBox1.Text;`?

Comment: You mean like this Request.Form[TextBox1.Text] . But I tried this as well but still getting null values. If you see my post I have put If Else condistion. In that if any of null values occured it goes to If condition which is nothing but display validation note i.e. emply feilds